# Mismatch Reputation in the thumbnail and the actual Reputation

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, users, users-page

Actually this was quite surprising. A casual troll in the Users Page revealed few users with negative vote. One example is here

[image]

Then trying to see what could have causes such a low reputation, I peeked inside the Profile Page of this particular User and was surprised to see a decent positive score.

[image]

Can someone explain to me how this can be possible?

Comment: [Suspicious behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5709932/revisions)

Comment: @animuson Woke my suspicions, at least.

Comment: @animuson: Or he's **really** grateful for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709932/update-panel-and-triggers-from-a-repeater-control/10250823#10250823). The user in question has transferred `2050` rep to the user [Guest](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1339428/guest?tab=reputation).

Comment: I think Guest is in for a nasty shock :-); 6th in rep this week! Something to add to the sock puppet finder detector maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your cursor hovers over the reputation, the tooltip says:

> reputation this week: -1486
>
> total reputation: 1948

Depending on whether you order the users by

- reputation:week
- reputation:month
- reputation:quarter
- reputation:year
- reputation:all

the displayed reputation is the one gained (or lost) in that period.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

The number you saw on the users page was that user's change in reputation for the current week, not their total reputation. Based on their [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726802/abcdefghi?tab=reputation&sort=post), the number on the users page looks correct, given the several 500 reputation bounties that user has placed in the past few days.